# Extend a class to have my custom class rendered as part of the Node graph?

Tags: javafx

In JavaFX, once I have a Scene, Pane, and/or Canvas setup and have my Node graph setup, how do I add my own custom components?  I've already added them to the Node graph, but they're not being rendered, because they neither inherit from a particular node nor implement the particular method necessary to have their rendering method called.  There isn't much complexity involved in drawing these components -- it's about twenty calls of `drawRectangle` etc..

If I recall correctly, in Swing, I had each component implement a version of `draw`, and `draw` was called automatically as part of the framework.  But I haven't found the equivalent mechanism in JavaFX yet.

Comment: FWIW, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something crucial.  I did a lot of searching and didn't find the answer, so I'm asking.  Thanks!

Comment: You say that they know how to draw themselves, but you also say that there is no graphics logic, you contradict yourself here, what do you want to realize? What have you already done? what are you missing ?

Comment: You do not draw your own components. You choose a suitable `Node` subclass to extend and add a property for adding the data. Based on this property you add/remove/update children. Alternatively you use some code to draw this on a `Canvas`...

Comment: Thanks, @fabian.  Would you recommend extending `Region`?  What do you mean by adding a property for adding the data?

Comment: It could work (see `Chart`), but sometimes `Control` is also used (`TreeView` ect...); For examples of properties for the data, see e.g. [`TableView.items`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#itemsProperty) or [`XYChart.data`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.html#dataProperty)

Answer (score 2):

JavaFX doesn't have "ondraw" in the usual sense, because components are usually composed and rendered on GPU.

There are multiple ways to create custom drawing, depending on your needs and requirements.

You can merely use [Canvas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html) for simple drawing, pretty clear described in [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/canvas.htm) . This is the simplest way for complex drawings and probably it is what you are looking for. Add canvas node to the scene and draw on it. You can encapsulate the logic by extending Canvas or a container component that will contain Canvas (or by presenter etc. if you employ some kind of MVP/MVC).

Another way is just to compose from existing visual components e.g. shapes and images, for example by extending or preparing a Pane or other container and adding children components.

Yet another is to prepare a bitmap with custom drawing and use Image component, you can use Swing or other APIs to draw a bitmap in advance and use it for rendering. In general this is similar to using canvas but more complex, unless you see clear benefits or have particular reasons, canvas is preferred.

Last way is to implement custom scene Node with complete rendering, I would not go into detail and advice against it; it is relatively complex, will use non-public APIs, probably would not be compatible between JDK releases and is useful only for very special needs.

Note, if you are creating a custom reusable library component, you probably will need to dive into the topic of [skinning and component lifecycle](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/UI+Controls+Architecture).

Comment: Thank you very much @fedor losev!  Your description of how to use the Canvas informed me of what I was missing.  As I figured it would be, it's so obvious in retrospect.  I'm going to make another answer that's the official answer, but thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. I think that my answer was exactly to the point of your (broad enough) question and enumerated the possibilities. The answer you've added is specific to something that you missed in your code and, strictly speaking, it is not a very a good answer to your own question (even if the question inspired by some specific case). So I'm not sure why do you need to add it as an "official" answer moreover why to add it at all. And technically, JavaFX is NOT so similar to the appoach in Swing.

Comment: Btw. if you got a satisfying answer, you can accept an answer so the question does not hang unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to pass in the `Pane` that I'm using for drawing into the constructor of my "custom class."  The custom class then adds the necessary shapes to the provided `pane`.  I assume I'll also need to keep track of those shapes as a data member of the custom class and remove/replace them when the custom class needs a new visual representation.

See Fedor Losev's answer below for a more complete list of options.  E.g., I could have used a Canvas instead of a Pane.

Comment: In simple application you can just extend Pane and encapsulate children creation inside, then add your extended class to the scene without the sequence `create pane, create separate custom class with pane argument, then add the pane to the stage` (*sometimes* it is good to separate in this way, but in this case probably not).

Comment: Yikes, I'm trying to run the Custom Class's function that draws on the `Pane` from a thread different than the main `Application` thread, and it seems that drawing in a thread other than the `Application` thread isn't supported.  I know what that means but now I need to redesign a bit....

Comment: Fedor Losev's idea of extending Pane and containing the child graphics should do the trick.

Comment: In usual case component access should be done solely on UI update thread (on which you already running when called from application start or events). If you have some long work, you can do in separate thread then call Platform.runLater() to make adjustments to UI. If you need to do things like animations, etc. there are AnimationTimer, Timeline and runLater for that. For very expensive drawings, preparing an image on separate thread and rendering it on UI can sometimes be a better solution than UI drawing or composition APIs (usually not the case).